# Javascript: Accessing member variable (array) of a class in member functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a member variable of a class which is an array in member function of a class but getting an error:

> Can not read property `'length'` of undefined

Class:

```
function BasicArgs(){
  var argDataType = new Uint8Array(1);
  var argData = new Uint32Array(1);
}
```

Member function:

```
BasicArgs.prototype.getByteStreamLength = function(){
  alert(this.argData.length);
  return i;
}
```

This is one of the example but i have come across this at many places.
variables like integer are easily accessible but most of the times problem is with arrays.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need `this` to make properties of the object in a constructor.

```
function BasicArgs(){
    this.argDataType = new Uint8Array(1);
    this.argData = new Uint32Array(1);
}
```

There's no way for prototyped functions to directly access the variable scope of the constructor function.

And then be sure to use `new` to invoke the constructor.

```
var ba = new BasicArgs();

ba.getByteStreamLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access private variable of function

modified code:

```
   function BasicArgs(){
      this.argDataType = new Uint8Array(1);
     this.argData = new Uint32Array(1);
    }

    BasicArgs.prototype.getByteStreamLength = function(){
       alert(this.argData.length);
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `var argData` doesn't create a property on the object.  It just creates a local variable that goes away as soon as the constructor exits.  You need to do

`this.argData = new Uint32Array(1)`

instead.

Comment: Not exactly correct. The variable will still exist, but it isn't accessible outside of the scope of the constructor.